# Can't enter multiple spaces in a row, in content editable div on Firefox 31

Tags: firefox, whitespace, contenteditable

My app uses content editable div as editor. 
My app has a lot of JavaScript code, including timer that modifies DOM asynchronously after key is pressed.

Problem: Press space key multiple times, only one space is entered; if press any non-space key, then one more space can be entered.

Examples: 
Press space 3 times. Result: only one space is entered in the content editable div.

Press space 3 times, then any non-space character, then space multiple times. Result: space non-space-character space.

This only happens on Firefox. It doesn't happen on Chrome or IE. 
I have Firefox night build and I can debug it. Where should I set break point in Firefox, so I can understand what's wrong with my app? 
Thanks!

Comment: +1. No expert, but in my opinion other browsers shouldn't support it. Normaly on every second space you would need a `&nbsp;` and in this case it is more design related then content.

Comment: Need some code or a demo page.

Comment: Reply Christian: the space isn't inserted by JS. The issue is keep pressing space key on the content editable div, Firefox should have inserted &nbsp.

Comment: Reply Tim: reducing to minimum repro is difficult as my app is large, that's why I am thinking to investigate from Firefox code and understand why my app prevents Firefox from behaving properly.